# MySQL: Copy specific columns from one database to another keeping primary key the same

Tags: mysql

I have two databases, dev and production. They both have the same tables and column structure.

I need to move some production data into dev, keeping the same primary key IDs but with a WHERE clause.

```
    UPDATE 
      dev.tableA, 
      prod.tableA
    SET 
      dev.tableA.title = prod.tableA.title,
      dev.tableA.url_title = prod.tableA.url_title,
      dev.tableA.status = prod.tableA.status,
      dev.tableA.edit_date = prod.tableA.edit_date
    WHERE 
      dev.tableA.entry_id = prod.tableA.entry_id
      AND prod.tableA.channel_id = 7
```

When I run the above query I get a 0 rows affected message.

I also tried this statement but again with 0 rows affected.

```
        UPDATE 
            dev.tableA dt
            INNER JOIN 
                prod.tableA tt
        ON 
            tt.entry_id = dt.entry_id
            SET 
                dt.title = tt.title,
                dt.url_title = tt.url_title,
            dt.status = tt.status,
            dt.edit_date = tt.edit_date
          WHERE 
            tt.channel_id = 7;
```

Comment: So there is data with the same `entry_id`s in the dev database already since you're using update and not insert?

Comment: That's correct. But I also need to insert some new rows that have been created in production but I figured that would be a separate INSERT statement unless there is a way to handle both at the same time?

Comment: Chances are that you can do this with a `INSERT IGNORE`. Alternatively, why not run a DELETE with that WHERE on the dev database, followed by a straight INSERT?

Comment: @Iserni they both sound good options but I'm not so strong with SQL. Could you provide examples?

Answer (score 0):

Your updates look fine, but will return 0 if the values were already the same; MySQL by default only tells you rows actually changed.

Though I would've indented more like this:

```
UPDATE dev.tableA AS dt
   INNER JOIN prod.tableA AS tt
      ON tt.entry_id = dt.entry_id
SET dt.title = tt.title
   , dt.url_title = tt.url_title
   , dt.status = tt.status
   , dt.edit_date = tt.edit_date
WHERE tt.channel_id = 7
;
```

I generally avoid `INSERT IGNORE` and `REPLACE INTO` queries; I've seen them cause way more issues than they are worth. Instead...

```
INSERT INTO tableA (id, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT id, field1, field2, field3
FROM tableB AS b
WHERE tableB.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tableA)
;
-- OR (the below version may be faster) --
INSERT INTO tableA (id, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT b.id, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
FROM tableB AS b
LEFT JOIN tableA AS a ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL -- assuming id is not nullable
;
```

and similarly...

```
DELETE FROM tableA 
WHERE tableA.field1 NOT IN (SELECT field1 FROM tableB)
;
-- OR (the below version may be faster) --
DELETE a 
FROM tableA AS a LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: @KoalaKid I just edited them a bit, so be sure to refresh.

Comment: I presume I can run those queries across two databases just be prepending the DB name in front of table name e.g. db_name.table_name?

Comment: @KoalaKid Yep, `db1.tableA AS a` AND `db2.tableA AS b` should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT` with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO dev.tableA (entry_id, title, url_title, status, edit_date)
SELECT entry_id, title, url_title, status, edit_date
FROM prod.tableA
WHERE channel_id = 7
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    title = VALUES(title), url_title = VALUES(url_title),
    status = VALUES(status), edit_date = VALUES(edit_date)
```

Comment: thanks for this. So would this insert new values and then update existing entries that had different data?

Comment: And I also have to run this on two other tables that all share the same entry_id as primary or foreign key. Is there a way to run this against all 3 at the same time?

Comment: q1: Yes, that's what it does. q2: You can only insert into one table at a time.